# Memory leak of SKAction.runAction() completion block(closure)

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I often use SKAction with completion block and use the variable that called runAction() in completion block, like this.

```
self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)) {
    self.removeFromParent()
}
```

Does this cause retain cycle?
I think, if SKNode does not have completion variable, retain cycle does not occur.
Is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you implement `deinit` and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result of my test, SKAction completion closure does not have strong reference.
In addition, if I add a closure as a variable to SKNode's subclass and access self in the closure, SKNode's deinit() had never called.